# How to remove character from odd index in Swift String

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift & I have to remove characters from odd index from a given String

I did try with following code

```
var myStringObject = "HelloTestString"

myStringObject.enumerated().filter({ index, char in !(char == "1" && index % 2 == 0) })
```

but I am unable to find the desired result string. Can you please guide me how to remove characters from odd index in String.

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter by two filter types. So you have to move to the old approach.

```
var myStringObject = "HelloTestString"

var newString = ""

var index = 0

while index < myStringObject.count {
    if index % 2 != 0 {
        let firstIndex: String.Index = myStringObject.startIndex
        let desiredChar: Character = myStringObject[myStringObject.index(firstIndex, offsetBy: index)]
        newString = newString + "\(desiredChar)"
    }
    index = index + 1
}

print(newString) //elTsSrn
```

Comment: `let firstIndex: String.Index = myStringObject.startIndex` might be put before the while loop since it shouldn't change and doesn't need to be recreated each time.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your starting solution:

```
let couples = myStringObject.enumerated().filter { (arg0) -> Bool in
    let (offset, _) = arg0
    return offset % 2 == 0
}
print(couples)
```

or

```
let couples = myStringObject.enumerated().filter { (offset, _) -> Bool in
    return offset % 2 == 0
} //Which is more similar to last version
```

You have then, an array of Tuples where first element is the offset, and the second the element.

```
$>[(offset: 0, element: "H"), (offset: 2, element: "l"), (offset: 4, element: "o"), (offset: 6, element: "e"), (offset: 8, element: "t"), (offset: 10, element: "t"), (offset: 12, element: "i"), (offset: 14, element: "g")]
```

Let's keep only the letters (and back to `String`, not a `String.Element`):

```
let onlyletters = couples.map({ String($0.element) })
```

Let's get it back into a String.

```
let result = onlyletters.joined()
```

In one line:

```
let oneLine = myStringObject.enumerated().filter({ $0.0 % 2 == 0 }).map({ String($0.element) }).joined()
```

Comment: The answer is `elTsSrn` but your answer is `Hloettig` , actually you are removing the even positions of the string.

Comment: % 2 != 0 then should do the trick. That’s an small modification, main logic remaining the same.

Comment: Slightly compact(!)er: `String(myStringObject.enumerated().compactMap({ $0 % 2 == 0 ? $1 : nil }))`

Comment: Good point, that avoid my joined() and the conversion in String for each element. String can be init with an array of String.Element then, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an auxiliary index and use `defer` to increase it after each iteration on your collection, this way you don't need to enumerate your string:

```
let string = "HelloTestString"
var index = 0
let filtered = string.filter { _ in
    defer { index += 1 }
    return index % 2 == 1
}
print(filtered) // "elTsSrn"
```

If you need to mutate your original string you can use removeAll with the same approach:

```
var string = "HelloTestString"
var index = 0
string.removeAll { _ in
    defer { index += 1 }
    return index % 2 == 0
}
print(string)
```

---

Implementing your own method 
extending `RangeReplaceableCollection` to `filter` or `removeAll` elements that are in odd or even positions:

---

```
extension  RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var oddIndicesElements: Self {
        var position = 0
        return filter { _ in
            defer { position += 1 } 
            return position % 2 == 1
        }
    }
    var evenIndicesElements: Self {
        var position = 0
        return filter { _ in
            defer { position += 1 }
            return position % 2 == 0
        }
    }
    mutating func removeAllEvenIndicesElements() {
        var position = 0
        removeAll { _ in
            defer { position += 1 }
            return position % 2 == 0
        }
    }
    mutating func removeAllOddIndicesElements() {
        var position = 0
        removeAll { _ in
            defer { position += 1 }
            return position % 2 == 1
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var myStringObject = "HelloTestString"
print(myStringObject.oddIndicesElements)  // "elTsSrn"

myStringObject.removeAllEvenIndicesElements()
print(myStringObject) // "elTsSrn"
```