# CodingBat string_bits problem solved using swit for loop

Tags: swift, loops

```
Question:
 
 Given a string, return a new string made of every other char starting with the first, so "Hello" yields "Hlo".

 string_bits('Hello') → 'Hlo'
 string_bits('Hi') → 'H'
 string_bits('Heeololeo') → 'Hello'
 
Solution:

func string_bits(userString: String) ->String{
    var myString = ""
    
    
    for(i, v) in userString.enumerated(){
        if i % 2 == 0{
            myString.append(v)
        }
    }
    return myString
}

Output: Hello
```

Now my question:
Is there any I can iterate my index any way in swift like object-c, c, or other programming languages does. For instance:

```
result = ""
  # On each iteration, add the substring of the chars 0..i
  for i in range(len(str)):
    result = result + str[:i+1] 
  return result
```

str[:i+1]
Here, I am adding +1 with the current index and getting the index value. How can I do this in swift.

Comment: Did you mean to use `stride()`, which would allow you do have a `for (i = 0; i < n; i +=2)` (for instance), and then you could use that `i+1` if needed.

Comment: @Larme my friend thanks for your quick reply. I didn't. let me check.

Comment: but how to pass that index number and get that index value? would you kindly add example?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451518/2303865

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan do you need every other index of your collection or just the elements?

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for asking. I want to know how to do like mystring[ index + 1 or +2]
and getting the desire index value in swift as other programming languages do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension Collection {
    func everyNthIndex(n: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<Index,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { index in
            guard index < endIndex else { return nil }
            defer { index = self.index(index, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex }
            return index
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for evenIndex in alphabet.everyNthIndex(n: 2) {
    print("evenIndex", evenIndex, "char:", alphabet[evenIndex])
}
for oddIndex in alphabet.dropFirst().everyNthIndex(n: 2) {
    print("oddIndex", oddIndex, "char:", alphabet[oddIndex])
}
```

---

regular approach using while loop:

```
var index = alphabet.startIndex
while index < alphabet.endIndex {
    defer { index = alphabet.index(index, offsetBy: 1) }
    print(alphabet[index])
    print(index)
}
```

or enumerating the string indices:

```
func string_bits(userString: String) -> String {
    var myString = ""
    for (offset,index) in userString.indices.enumerated() {
        if offset.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            myString.append(userString[index])
        }
    }
    return myString
}
```

Comment: I got your thanks for your time. That's meant that there is no way like objective-c, python, and other Programming languages.

Comment: As I said String is not indexed by an integer but you can offset it  as shown above `yourString.index(index, offsetBy: n)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection/3024461-index